# JQuery Ajax call on anchor tag click

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets, anchor

I am new to jQuery and trying to learn it example by example
In the below example, I am trying to call a servlet on an event of anchor tag click using jQUery Ajax. I have more than one anchor tag in my page and I want a different servlet to be invoked for each of them. If I use the id of anchor tag like **$('#submit1').click** as in below example it is not working. But, if I replace it with 'a' it is working which invokes the same servlet for both of anchor tags

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>AJAX calls using Jquery in Servlet</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">   
        </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {                        
                $('#submit1').click(function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();   
                    var username=$('#user').val();
                $.get('ActionServlet',{user:username},function(responseText) { 
                        $('#welcometext').text(responseText);         
                    });
                });
            });

            $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
                $('#content_progress').text("Loading...");
            });

            $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
                $('#content_progress').text("");
            });

        </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1">
      <h1>AJAX Demo using Jquery in JSP and Servlet</h1>
           Enter your Name:
           <input type="text" id="user"/><br>

           <a name="submit1" href="#">View Profile</a>
           <a name="submit2" href="#">Course Details</a>
           <br/>
</form>
     <div id="content_progress">
     </div>
     <div id="welcometext">
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector)

change `name=submit1`

to

`id=submit1`

```
<a id="submit1" href="#">View Profile</a>
```

or

[attribute-equals-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

if you want access by `a` tag by `name`

change `$('#submit1').click(function(event) {`

to

`$('a[name="submit1"]').click(function(event) {`

Answer (score 1):

You need to give `id` to `a` not `name`, `#` is the [id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector) so the value must be the id attribute value of the targeted element

```
<a id="submit1" href="#">View Profile</a>
<a id="submit2" href="#">Course Details</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have yet another problem now. I getting a form, that allows user change his/her password, as an ajax response from a servlet. Now, I added ajax functionality to buttons in the new form also, but when I click **Change Password** button, the whole form is vanishing, instead, I want to invoke a servlet again on clicking **Change Password**. I am making sure that jsp file **test.jsp** that receives response from ajax call already includes ajax logic for the id of change password **#changePswd**

**test.jsp**:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>AJAX calls using Jquery in Servlet</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {                        

        $('#submit1').click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();   
                $.get('ActionServlet',{request:"form"},function(responseText) { 
                $('#welcometext').html(responseText);         
            });
        });

        $('#changePswd').click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();   
                $.get('ActionServlet',{request:"action"},function(responseText) { 
                $('#content_progress').html(responseText);       
            });
        });

    });

    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        $('#content_progress').text("Loading...");
    });

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
        $('#content_progress').text("");
    });

</script>

</head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1">
            <h1>AJAX Demo using Jquery in JSP and Servlet</h1>
            Enter your Name: <input type="text" id="user" /><br>

            <a id="submit1" href="#">View Profile</a> 
            <a name="submit2" href="#">Course Details</a> <br />

            <div id="content_progress"></div>
            <div id="welcometext"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Servlet**:

```
package ajaxdemo;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ActionServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ActionServlet() {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        String requestType=null;
        String data = null;

        requestType = request.getParameter("request").toString();

        if(requestType.equals("form"))
        {
            data = "<form id = \"formChangePswd\"><table><tbody>"
                +"<tr><td class=\"style1\">Old Password</td><td class=\"style2\"><input type=\"text\" id=\"oldPswd\" size=\"20\" class=\"textchange\" /></td></tr>"
                +"<tr><td class=\"style1\">New Password</td><td class=\"style2\"><input type=\"text\" id=\"newPswd\" size=\"20\" class=\"textchange\"/></td></tr>"
                +"<tr><td class=\"style1\">Confirm New Password</td><td class=\"style2\"><input type=\"text\" id=\"confirmPswd\" size=\"20\" class=\"textchange\"/></td></tr>"
                +"<tr></tr><tr><td align=\"right\" class=\"style1\"><input type=\"reset\" id=\"reset\" value=\"Reset\" /></td><td class=\"style2\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"changePswd\" value=\"Change Password\"/></td>"
                +"</tr></tbody></table></form>";
        }
        else if(requestType.equals("action"))
        {
            data = "Your request is lodged, we will get back to you soon";
        }

        response.setContentType("text/html");  
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 
        response.getWriter().write(data); 
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Make it as new question than only more people will see this question and help you

Comment: try `$('#changePswd').click(function(event) {` to `$(document).on('click', '#changePswd', function(event) {` http://api.jquery.com/on/